# Can't logon to xfce4

Tags: 18.04, xfce, gdm

I'm using Ubuntu 18.04 bionic and installed the xfce4 package. However, when I choose "Xfce session" in the login manager, it does not log me on to Xfce4 but instead throws me right back to the login window. Why is this and how can I fix it?

Comment: You have what's called a "login loop". It could result from any number of things.  But start your search with that term... While you *can* use multiple desktop environments on the same install, it often requires more work than just installing the meta package for the DE.  A DE is actually *dozens* of packages and they don't always play well with the *other* installed desktop environment. This is the reason that Ubuntu comes in different flavors. Xubuntu is the official Ubuntu flavor using xfce

Comment: I get this same issue if I go from another Desktop Environment to Xfce4.  As long as I have chosen the Xfce4 and tried to log in, then I reboot the system and then it should still be on the Xfce4 then I can log in.  It doesn't happen on every DE switching back to Xfce4.

Comment: @Terrance BOOM, seems like a reboot did the trick. I didn't even realized that I hadn't rebooted after I installed XFCE4. Login works fine after a reboot, Thanks, you can move it to an answer and I'll accept!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I get this same issue if I go from another Desktop Environment to Xfce4 (Xubuntu). As long as I have chosen the Xfce4 (Xubuntu) and tried to log in and it loops, I then reboot the system and then it should still be on the Xfce4 (Xubuntu) then I can log in. It doesn't happen on every DE switching back to Xfce4.

**Update 07/02/2021:**

You can fix this permanently by adding the following line to `/etc/gdm3/PostSession/Default` (this also works in 20.04 using GDM3):

```
killall -9 -u $USER
```

So that the `PostSession/Default` file looks like:

```
#!/bin/sh
killall -9 -u $USER
exit 0
```

Then just logout and log back in using the DE of your choice.

Hope this helps!